# android - Error java.lang.NumberFormatException : For input string, program stops working

Tags: java, android, numberformatexception

This is how the code looks, at first it was running properly but after adding new functions of buttons, this segment of code didn't run properly like before. Please help me I have a submission on Wednesday this week. It is possible that is this is a bug?

```
package com.example.calculator;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    TextView txtbtn;
    float mValueOne, mValueTwo;
    double a;
    double ans=0;
    boolean mAddition, mSubtract, mMultiplication, mDivision, mArithmetic, mReminder,
    power2nd, mSin, mCos, mTan, mSinH, mCosH, mTanH;
    ImageButton deletebutton;
    Button clearbutton, dividebutton, multiplybutton, button7, button8, button9, minusbutton,
            button4, button5, button6, plusbutton, button1, button2, button3, button0, pointbutton,
            equalbutton, xcubebutton, squarebutton, modulusbutton, exponentbutton, tenexponentbutton,
            piebutton, squarerootbutton, cuberootbutton, stpower2nd, xfactorialbutton, logbutton, lnbutton,
            sinbutton, cosbutton, tanbutton, sinhbutton, coshbutton, tanhbutton, oneoverxbutton, absbutton,
            floorbutton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                //| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
                //| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        scientific_operation();

    }
    public void scientific_operation(){
        txtbtn = findViewById(R.id.txt);
        deletebutton = findViewById(R.id.BB);
        clearbutton = findViewById(R.id.C);
        dividebutton = findViewById(R.id.Bdivide);
        multiplybutton = findViewById(R.id.Bmulti);
        button7 = findViewById(R.id.B7);
        button8 = findViewById(R.id.B8);
        button9 = findViewById(R.id.B9);
        minusbutton = findViewById(R.id.Bsubtract);
        button4 = findViewById(R.id.B4);
        button5 = findViewById(R.id.B5);
        button6 = findViewById(R.id.B6);
        plusbutton = findViewById(R.id.Bplus);
        button1 = findViewById(R.id.B1);
        button2 = findViewById(R.id.B2);
        button3 = findViewById(R.id.B3);
        button0 = findViewById(R.id.B0);
        pointbutton = findViewById(R.id.MCdot);
        equalbutton = findViewById(R.id.Bequal);
        cuberootbutton = findViewById(R.id.cuberoot);
        squarerootbutton = findViewById(R.id.squareroot);
        xcubebutton = findViewById(R.id.powerX3);
        squarebutton = findViewById(R.id.powerX2);
        modulusbutton = findViewById(R.id.Bmod);
        exponentbutton = findViewById(R.id.expower);
        tenexponentbutton = findViewById(R.id.X10X);
        piebutton = findViewById(R.id.pi);
        oneoverxbutton = findViewById(R.id.onebyx);
        xfactorialbutton = findViewById(R.id.xfactorial);
        stpower2nd = findViewById(R.id.power2nd);
        logbutton = findViewById(R.id.log);
        lnbutton = findViewById(R.id.ln);
        sinhbutton = findViewById(R.id.arcsin);
        coshbutton = findViewById(R.id.arccos);
        tanhbutton = findViewById(R.id.arctan);
        sinbutton = findViewById(R.id.sin);
        cosbutton = findViewById(R.id.cos);
        tanbutton = findViewById(R.id.tan);
        absbutton = findViewById(R.id.abs);
        floorbutton = findViewById(R.id.floor);


        absbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    a = Math.abs(Double.parseDouble(txtbtn.getText().toString()));
                    txtbtn.setText("");
                    txtbtn.setText(txtbtn.getText().toString() + a);

                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    //
                }
            }
        });

        floorbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    a = Math.floor(Double.parseDouble(txtbtn.getText().toString()));
                    txtbtn.setText("");
                    txtbtn.setText(txtbtn.getText().toString() + a);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    //
                }
            }
        });

        stpower2nd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    mValueOne = Float.parseFloat(txtbtn.getText() + "");
                    power2nd = true;
                    txtbtn.setText(null);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    //
                }
            }
        });

        deletebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                try{
                    String str;
                    str = txtbtn.getText().toString();
                    str = str.substring(0, str.length()-1);
                    txtbtn.setText(str);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    //
                }
            }
        });

        clearbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                txtbtn.setText("");
            }
        });

        dividebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                txtbtn.setText(null);
            }
        });

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                txtbtn.setText(txtbtn.getText()+ "1");
                mArithmetic = true;
            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                txtbtn.setText(txtbtn.getText()+ "2");
                mArithmetic = true;
            }
        });

        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                txtbtn.setText(txtbtn.getText()+ "3");
                mArithmetic = true;
            }
        });

        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                txtbtn.setText(txtbtn.getText()+ "4");
                mArithmetic = true;
            }
        });

        button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                txtbtn.setText(txtbtn.getText()+ "5");
                mArithmetic = true;
            }
        });

        button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                txtbtn.setText(txtbtn.getText()+ "6");
                mArithmetic = true;
            }
        });

        button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                txtbtn.setText(txtbtn.getText()+ "7");
                mArithmetic = true;
            }
        });

        button8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                txtbtn.setText(txtbtn.getText()+ "8");
                mArithmetic = true;
            }
        });

        button9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                txtbtn.setText(txtbtn.getText()+ "9");
                mArithmetic = true;
            }
        });

        button0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                txtbtn.setText(txtbtn.getText()+ "0");
                mArithmetic = true;
            }
        });

        plusbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    mValueOne = Float.parseFloat(txtbtn.getText() + "");
                    mAddition = true;
                    txtbtn.setText(null);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    //
                }
            }
        });

        minusbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    mValueOne = Float.parseFloat(txtbtn.getText() + "");
                    mSubtract = true;
                    txtbtn.setText(null);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    //
                }
            }
        });

        multiplybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    mValueOne = Float.parseFloat(txtbtn.getText() + "");
                    mMultiplication = true;
                    txtbtn.setText(null);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    //
                }
            }
        });

        dividebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    mValueOne = Float.parseFloat(txtbtn.getText() + "");
                    mDivision = true;
                    txtbtn.setText(null);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    //
                }
            }
        });

        cuberootbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    a = Math.cbrt(Double.parseDouble(txtbtn.getText().toString()));
                    txtbtn.setText("");
                    txtbtn.setText(txtbtn.getText().toString() + a);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    //
                }
            }
        });

        squarerootbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    a = Math.sqrt(Double.parseDouble(txtbtn.getText().toString()));
                    txtbtn.setText("");
                    txtbtn.setText(txtbtn.getText().toString() + a);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    //
                }
            }
        });

        xcubebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    a = Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(txtbtn.getText().toString()), 3);
                    txtbtn.setText("");
                    txtbtn.setText(txtbtn.getText().toString() + a);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    //
                }
            }
        });

        squarebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    a = Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(txtbtn.getText().toString()), 2);
                    txtbtn.setText("");
                    txtbtn.setText(txtbtn.getText().toString() + a);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    //
                }
            }
        });

        modulusbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    mValueOne = Float.parseFloat(txtbtn.getText() + "");
                    mReminder = true;
                    txtbtn.setText(null);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    //
                }
            }
        });

        exponentbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    a = Math.exp(Double.parseDouble(txtbtn.getText().toString()));
                    txtbtn.setText("");
                    txtbtn.setText(txtbtn.getText().toString() + a);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    //
                }
            }
        });

        tenexponentbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    int n = Integer.parseInt(txtbtn.getText().toString());
                    int exp = (int) Math.pow(10,n);
                    txtbtn.setText(exp + "");
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    //
                }
            }
        });

        piebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtbtn.setText(Math.PI + "");

            }
        });

        oneoverxbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    a = 1/Double.parseDouble(txtbtn.getText().toString());
                    txtbtn.setText("");
                    txtbtn.setText(txtbtn.getText().toString() + a);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    //
                }
            }
        });

        xfactorialbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    a = Double.parseDouble(txtbtn.getText().toString());
                    int er = 0; double i, s = 1;
                    if(a < 0){
                        er = 20;
                    }
                    else{
                        for(i = 2; i <= a; i += 1.0)
                            s *= i;
                    }
                    txtbtn.setText("");
                    txtbtn.setText(txtbtn.getText().toString() + s);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    //
                }
            }
        });

        logbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    a = Math.log10(Double.parseDouble(txtbtn.getText().toString()));
                    txtbtn.setText("");
                    txtbtn.setText(txtbtn.getText().toString() + a);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    //
                }
            }
        });

        lnbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    a = Math.log(Double.parseDouble(txtbtn.getText().toString()));
                    txtbtn.setText("");
                    txtbtn.setText(txtbtn.getText().toString() + a);
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    //
                }
            }
        });

        sinhbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                txtbtn.setText("arc_sin");
                mSinH = true;
            }
        });

        coshbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                txtbtn.setText("arc_cos");
                mCosH = true;
            }
        });

        tanhbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                txtbtn.setText("arc_tan");
                mTanH = true;
            }
        });

        sinbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtbtn.setText("sin");
                mSin = true;
            }
        });

        cosbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtbtn.setText("cos");
                mCos = true;
            }
        });

        tanbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtbtn.setText("tan");
                mTan = true;
            }
        });

        exponentbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    Double n = Double.parseDouble(txtbtn.getText().toString());
                    Double exp = Math.pow(2.718281828, n);
                    txtbtn.setText(exp + "");
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    //
                }
            }
        });

        equalbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mSinH){
                    if(mArithmetic){
                        String str;
                        str = txtbtn.getText().toString();
                        str = str.substring(4);
                        a = Math.asin(Double.parseDouble(str));
                        txtbtn.setText(a + "");
                        mArithmetic = false;
                        mSinH = false;

                    }
                }
                if(mCosH){
                    if(mArithmetic){
                        String str;
                        str = txtbtn.getText().toString();
                        str = str.substring(4);
                        a = Math.acos(Double.parseDouble(str));
                        txtbtn.setText(a + "");
                        mArithmetic = false;
                        mCosH = false;

                    }
                }
                if(mTanH){
                    if(mArithmetic){
                        String str;
                        str = txtbtn.getText().toString();
                        str = str.substring(4);
                        a = Math.atan(Double.parseDouble(str));
                        txtbtn.setText(a + "");
                        mArithmetic = false;
                        mTanH = false;

                    }
                }

                if(mAddition){
                    mValueTwo = Float.parseFloat(txtbtn.getText() + "");
                    txtbtn.setText(mValueOne + mValueTwo + "");
                    mAddition = false;
                }

                if(mSubtract){
                    mValueTwo = Float.parseFloat(txtbtn.getText() + "");
                    txtbtn.setText(mValueOne - mValueTwo + "");
                    mSubtract = false;
                }

                if(mMultiplication){
                    mValueTwo = Float.parseFloat(txtbtn.getText() + "");
                    txtbtn.setText(mValueOne * mValueTwo + "");
                    mMultiplication = false;

                }
                if(mDivision){
                    mValueTwo = Float.parseFloat(txtbtn.getText() + "");
                    txtbtn.setText(mValueOne / mValueTwo + "");
                    mDivision = false;
                }
                if(mReminder){
                    mValueTwo = Float.parseFloat(txtbtn.getText() + "");
                    txtbtn.setText(mValueOne % mValueTwo + "");
                    mReminder = false;
                }
                if(power2nd){
                    mValueTwo = Float.parseFloat(txtbtn.getText() + "");
                    double exp = Math.pow(mValueOne, mValueTwo);
                    txtbtn.setText(exp + "");
                    power2nd = false;
                }

                if(mSin){
                    if(mArithmetic){
                        String str;
                        str = txtbtn.getText().toString();
                        str = str.substring(3);
                        a = Math.sin(Double.parseDouble(str));
                        txtbtn.setText(a + "");
                        mArithmetic = false;
                        mSin = false;
                    }
                }
                if(mCos){
                    if(mArithmetic){
                        String str;
                        str = txtbtn.getText().toString();
                        str = str.substring(3);
                        a = Math.cos(Double.parseDouble(str));
                        txtbtn.setText(a + "");
                        mArithmetic = false;
                        mCos = false;
                    }
                }
                if(mTan){
                    if(mArithmetic){
                        String str;
                        double a;
                        str = txtbtn.getText().toString();
                        str = str.substring(3);
                        a = Math.tan(Float.parseFloat(str));
                        txtbtn.setText(a + "");
                        mArithmetic = false;
                        mTan = false;
                    }
                }
                ans = Double.parseDouble(txtbtn.getText().toString());
            }
        });

        pointbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtbtn.setText(txtbtn.getText() + ".");
            }
        });

    }

}
```

This is the program error it showed, I tried searching for few questions in this page but I wasn't actually getting the expected answer

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.calculator, PID: 1574
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "sin1"
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
        at com.example.calculator.MainActivity$40.onClick(MainActivity.java:536)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "arc_sin1"` `arc_sin1` is not a number. Where is in your code?

Comment: Sorry sir, arc_sin and 1 are buttons in the calculator. After pressing both, the program stopped working.

Comment: In the stacktrace I can see a `parseDouble`. Which is the line `MainActivity$40.onClick(MainActivity.java:648)`?

Comment: Yes that particular line sir, I have used double aa = 0 to initialize it to the string:
aa = Math.asin(Double.parseDouble(str)

Comment: Debug your code and check what is the value of str.

Comment: I debug the code but can't find the value of str

Comment: This is might be because 

     `txtbtn.setText("") //this mean this is empty`

you cannot convert empty data in int , float or double . if your field contain only number then only you can convert that into number.

Comment: Please help me to elaborate more, how to correct this field? I used the same variables for sin, cos and tan operation and it works fine

Comment: ` java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "sin1"` this mean your string is "sin1"  . this contain string which is "sin" .